# Are there any alternative JS ports of Box2D?

Tags: javascript, box2d, html5, html-canvas

I have been thinking about creating a top down 2D car game for HTML5. For my first game I wrote the physics and collisions my self but for this one I would like to use some ready made library.

I found out Box2D and its JS port.

http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net

It seems to be quite old port, made in 2008. Is it lacking many features of current Box2D or does it have major issues with it? And are there any alternatives for it?

Comment: -1 because there are known issues with all software. Specific questions, please.

Comment: I don't know if your comment was before or after the edit, but I think it's pretty clear that the OP is asking for major issues that could be serious problems (e.g. using more than X joints will crash the program) not any known issue

Comment: It was before the edit, but I still think it's a bad question. For example, using more than 10,000,000 joints will crash the program for sure. Without _specific_ concerns, this question is effectively "Please review <software>" - that's not a very good question. The SE format is good for focused questions; Google is better for general overviews. (You'll notice that neither answer gives actual issues with Box2D JS, just a point towards an alternative, which might as well re-ask the question.)

Comment: Now the question has been edited beyond recognition - and when asked this way becomes trivially Googleable - and since it's asking for a list of things, it's probably best as CW.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628078/which-box2d-javascript-library-should-i-use

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Box2D has a kind of maintained version on github:

https://github.com/thinkpixellab/pl/tree/master/src/box2d

Microsoft is using it for at least on of their IE9 test drive demos.

Comment: 'Microsoft is using it for at least on of their IE9 test drive demos.' is that really something to be proud of?

Comment: @WTP Have you even tried some of the JS and Canvas demos in IE9? The entire browser is hardware accelerated, and has some of the fastest HTML5 performance across the board. Just because a version of browser sucked 10 years ago, doesn't mean it still does.

Comment: @AttackingHobo, +1, IE6, 7 really suck. 8 More or less. 9 or 10 are decent browsers. Stop hating the entire family because of a few outdated family members.

Answer (score 16):

There's box2dweb, which is a much newer port and has a lot fewer issues than box2djs. I highly recommend it.

http://code.google.com/p/box2dweb/

Comment: So there are three versions at the moment? http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net https://github.com/thinkpixellab/box2d and http://code.google.com/p/box2dweb/

Comment: Yes, although it looks like Box2Dweb is being actively developed (last checkin 1/23/11) whereas the github one is less so (last checkin 10/29/10). Also, Box2Dweb has an active roadmap for where it's going next: http://code.google.com/p/box2dweb/wiki/Roadmap

Comment: This version is also good - https://github.com/HBehrens/box2d.js

Comment: I started playing with box2dweb. It looks ok for now. Also - there is good documentation: http://www.box2dflash.org/docs/2.1a/reference/

Answer (score 3):

A popular alternative (though not a port) is [cannon.js](https://github.com/schteppe/cannon.js), a "lightweight 3D physics engine" for the web.

Answer (score 2):

Also:

- Ports of JBox2D to GWT:

  - http://code.google.com/p/gwtbox2d/ (with demos)
  - https://github.com/simbit/gwt-box2d
  - http://code.google.com/p/box4gwt/
- Port to Node.js: https://github.com/jadell/box2dnode

I also remember a port for the original C++ code to JavaScript using [Emscripten](http://emscripten.org/) ie. LLVM but I can't seem to find it back. Only found https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/22
Too bad, I find interesting to adapt the original code rather than a port of a port...

Comment: Good ol' familiar JBox2D also supports GWT right out of the box, too!

Comment: @Groomblecom Maybe not at the time I wrote that, because GWT didn't support all of Java (and still doesn't, I guess). Java and GWT evolved since then. Good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't Box2D, there is a port of JigLib (3D Physics) to JS: https://github.com/supereggbert/JigLibJS. I haven't used it, but it was ported to be used in the GLGE WebGL library.

Answer (score 0):

There is very good alternative for Box2D-JS, just see [box2dweb](http://code.google.com/p/box2dweb/). See [this game](http://pixsansar.com/box2dweb-jumping-and-puzzle-ball-menu) which is built using box2dweb. You can make your project easily using this physics engine.